# iOS Integrate PlaceILive to replace Google Maps SDK

Tags: ios, maps

After allot of searching and googling, still can't find any reliable docs or support on how to integrate the PlaceILive(beta) on iOS App. Is there any SDK or framework for it?

Answer (score 0):

PlaceiLive is not yet provided any sdk to integrate in ios ,  but they have some [api that you can use](http://api.placeilive.com/v1/)